# How do I specify a build number from another project in my test execution?

Tags: testing, azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps + Test Plans and I am trying to figure out how to refer to a pipeline in another project (which is responsible for the production builds, but kept separate from the component pipelines on one project)

However, when I try to select the project it is grayed out.  I have project admin rights on both projects.

Comment: It is depends on what you want to do for the pipeline in another project? To triger another pipeline or pass some variables to another pipeline? If you are using the Classic pipeline, you may need use the REST API, or if you are using the YAML, you could use the dependencies for stages, jobs, step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I'm not trying to trigger, I just want to get a list of build numbers from another project and link to it to the test execution